# First order condition (consumer problem)

Tags: calculus, lagrange-multiplier, economics

Can you help me find the first-order condition of the following problem with respect to α:

$max[u(C_t) + δ *E_t[u(C_{t+1})]]$, such that:

$C_t=e_t-αp_t$, and

$C_{t+1}=e_{t+1}+αX_{t+1}$

For context this is the consumer problem ,

$C_t$: consumption at t

$e_t$: endowments at t

$p_t$: price of the risky asset

$α$: nb of shares purchased of risky asset

$δ$: a subjective discounting factor

$X_{t+1}$: random payoff

so we can write:

$max[u(e_t-αp_t) + δ *E_t[u(e_{t+1}+αX_{t+1}]]$

For the FOC, I arrive to this:

$u'(c_t)+δ*E_t[u'(C_{t+1})]=0$

$-p_t+δ*E_t[X_{t+1}]=0$

But the answer in my notes is:

**$-p_t*u'(C_t)+E_t[δ*u'(C_{t+1})*X_{t+1}]=0$**

Comment: It should be $C_{\color{red}{t+1}}=e_{t+1}+αX_{t+1}$.

Comment: I made the changes, thank you!

Comment: I've made an edit of my answer in order to make it more clear, hopefully. Feel free to ask, if something is still unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to apply the *chain rule*. Let's take the function $h(x)=f(g(x))$. Then the derivative is $h^{'}(x) = f'(g(x))\cdot  g^{'}(x)$.

Now you want to differentiate $u(g(\alpha))=u(e_t-\alpha p_t)$ w.r.t. $\alpha$. This is $u^{'}(g(\alpha))\cdot g'(\alpha)=u^{'}(e_t-\alpha p_t)'\cdot (-p_t)=u^{'}(C_t)\cdot (-p_t)$.

Similar for the other summand:

$\delta\cdot  \mathbb E_t[u(g(\alpha))]= δ \cdot \mathbb E_t[u(e_{t+1}+αX_{t+1})]$

$\left(\delta\cdot  \mathbb E_t[u(g(\alpha))]\right)^{'}=\delta\cdot  \mathbb E_t[u^{'}(g(\alpha))\cdot g^{'}(\alpha)]$

$= δ \cdot \mathbb E_t[u'(e_{t+1}+αX_{t+1})\cdot X_{t+1}]=δ \cdot \mathbb E_t[u'(C_{t+1})\cdot X_{t+1}]$

Then the derivative of a sum is the sum of the derivatives. So in total the FOC is

$u^{'}(C_t)\cdot (-p_t)+δ \cdot \mathbb E_t[u'(C_{t+1})\cdot X_{t+1}]=0$

Comment: Thank you so much!! I realized that the root of my problem was I didn't see the use of the chain rule. It's much more clear now. 
Cheers

Comment: @AlexisBoudreau You're welcome. Feel free to accept the answer.